# Select where clause by exact numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can use WHERE CLAUSE IN when my COLUMN1 datatype is CHARACTER:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE COLUMN1 IN ('A', 'B', 'C');
```

But when I tried to use WHERE CLAUSE IN when my COLUMN2 datatype is NUMERIC, I will have Syntax Error. As below statement:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 
WHERE COLUMN2 IN (1,2,3);
```

I know there is a BETWEEN but it's not fulfill what I need as I'm not selecting in Range but in Exact number series.

Thanks.

Comment: Both selects should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The one problem that I can think of is when `column1` is not a numeric type.  This will return an error when you try to compare to an integer (such as using `in`).

You can try the following to mimic the error:

```
select *
from (select cast('1' as varchar(255)) as val) t1
where val in (1, 2);
```

Be careful to have constants be the correct type.